# Synology NAS Volume Crashed - SHR RAID

Tags: raid, network-attached-storage, synology, crash

I have synalogy DS414j with 4 WD disk ( each of size 3726 GB ). I have 1 volume with Synology Hybrid RAID with capacity of 10.82 TB ( 10.67 TB Used)

One of the disks (Disk 1) was not being detected hence I shut down the device and reinserted it. The Disk is now in `Initialized` state

I looked into Synology doc https://kb.synology.com/en-ph/DSM/tutorial/How_can_I_repair_a_degraded_storage_space_in_a_high_availability_cluster but that will erase the data on Disk 1 and copy the data from remaining.

I thought I was a good idea to backup the data first and initiated a copy. I was able to copy a few TBs but now Disk 4 is in crashed state because it has 4 bad sectors. This has caused the whole volume to crash I am not sure how to move forward without any loss of data.

Is there any way I can force Disk 1 to be added back to the Raid (since I have never formatted the drive itself) ? or do something about the current state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover an mdadm array on Synology NAS with drive in "E" state?](https://serverfault.com/questions/568166/how-to-recover-an-mdadm-array-on-synology-nas-with-drive-in-e-state)
You have probably lost the needed metadata on Disk 1, don't do anything with it. It might be better to try to get all data out of it first.
If data is really important, get new drivers and make sector sector copies of the existing ones before doing anything more.

Comment: @NiKiZe the above answer points to rebuilding the array indexes, which would eventually fail as I have bad sectors on other drives. also this link https://www.dsebastien.net/2015/05/19/recovering-a-raid-array-in-e-state-on-a-synology-nas throws 404

Comment: You should be able to force restart your array to copy out data, but as I said. If data is important you must clone the drives individually first. And that would also solve bad blocks issue.

Comment: will attempt to backup everything to google,  might take 4 -6 weeks. Will attempt to force restart array